Defining Agent in LLamaIndex and Mistral 7B is throwing Attribute error
I am using llamaIndex and locally downloaded Mistral model (mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q4_K_M.gguf). I have created the python binding for this model using "llama-cpp". On defining the agent using:
'''
worker1 = FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tools([query_engine_tool], llm=llm, verbose=True,allow_parallel_tool_calls=True,)

'''
But on executing it I am getting the following error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[43], line 2
      1 # define Agent and agent service
----> 2 worker1 = FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tools(
      3     [query_engine_tool], llm=llm, verbose=True,allow_parallel_tool_calls=True,
      4 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\multiagent\Lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\agent\function_calling\step.py:158, in FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tools(cls, tools, tool_retriever, llm, verbose, max_function_calls, callback_manager, system_prompt, prefix_messages, **kwargs)
    154     prefix_messages = [ChatMessage(content=system_prompt, role="system")]
    156 prefix_messages = prefix_messages or []
--> 158 return cls(
    159     tools=tools,
    160     tool_retriever=tool_retriever,
    161     llm=llm,
    162     prefix_messages=prefix_messages,
    163     verbose=verbose,
    164     max_function_calls=max_function_calls,
    165     callback_manager=callback_manager,
    166     **kwargs,
    167 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\multiagent\Lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\agent\function_calling\step.py:103, in FunctionCallingAgentWorker.__init__(self, tools, llm, prefix_messages, verbose, max_function_calls, callback_manager, tool_retriever, allow_parallel_tool_calls)
    100 """Init params."""
    101 if not llm.metadata.is_function_calling_model:
    102     raise ValueError(
--> 103         f"Model name {llm.model} does not support function calling API. "
    104     )
    105 self._llm = llm
    106 self._verbose = verbose

AttributeError: 'LlamaCPP' object has no attribute 'model'

I am doing the development using python. Any help will be highly appreciated.
